# How can i fill missing values in data frame's outside data with resample function?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

I have dataframe like this:

Data set:

```
  datetime           value

2017-04-23 00:00:00+00:00 74

2017-04-23 00:01:00+00:00 74

2017-04-23 00:02:00+00:00 74

.
.
.  

2017-04-23 23:46:00+00:00 103

2017-04-23 23:47:00+00:00 103

2017-04-23 23:48:00+00:00 80
```

I want to resample missing value with this resample command:

```py
df.set_index('fusedDate').resample('5min').mean().ffill().reset_index()
```

But this code not resample value at 23:50, 23:55

Code Output:

```
2017-04-23 00:05:00+00:00 mean value of 5 min bin

2017-04-23 00:10:00+00:00 mean

2017-04-23 00:15:00+00:00 mean

...

2017-04-23 23:45:00+00:00 mean
```

Expected:

```
2017-04-23 00:05:00+00:00 mean value of 5 min bin

2017-04-23 00:10:00+00:00 mean

2017-04-23 00:15:00+00:00 mean

...

2017-04-23 23:45:00+00:00 mean

2017-04-23 23:50:00+00:00 mean

2017-04-23 23:55:00+00:00 mean
```

How can i fill missing values in dataframe's outside data with resample function  ?

Comment: Can you create a more concrete test data?   And, also include expected output from this new test data?

Comment: I added expected part to my question.

Comment: `df.set_index('fusedDate').resample('5min').mean().reindex(pd.date_range(df.index.min, '2017-04-23 23:55:00', freq='5Min).ffill().reset_index()`